# Laravel how to replace specific string with another string in Blade view

Tags: laravel

In my project I have events table and the user can store events in it

One of this table columns is `video` that accepts YouTube URL

And in the events page I need to embed the video he entered

Let's say we have this link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt-Wf7d0CFo

I need when displaying the video to remove `watch?v=` and replace it with `embed/`

How to do this in Laravel blade view?

```
<iframe class="w-100" height="315" src="{{ $event->video }}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Use [str_​replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Or create an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: Or Laravel's `Str::replace(...)` method: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-replace

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```php
$string = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt-Wf7d0CFo';
 
$replaced = Str::replace('watch?v=', 'embed/', $string);

// It will write out: https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vt-Wf7d0CFo
```

OR

```php
$string = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt-Wf7d0CFo';
 
$replaced = str_replace('watch?v=', 'embed/', $string);

// It will write out: https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vt-Wf7d0CFo
```

So in your case it would be:

```html
<iframe class="w-100" height="315" src="{{ str_replace('watch?v=', 'embed/', $event->video) }}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```